# How to print CCK field on product page if radio button attribute is selected

Tags: 6, theming, ubercart

I would like to print the contents of a specific field when an Ubercart product's radio button attribute is selected. For instance,

Radio Button with options A, B, and C.

If "A" is selected, no change.

If "B" is selected, show data from field "1".

If "C" is selected, show data from field "2".

How can I add this functionality to my product page tpl file?

Thanks!

Comment: use conditional field module

Comment: @Bala, I should have been clearer in my initial question... the radio button attribute is part of the Ubercart product page "add to cart" form, so I don't believe it would be eligible to be a part of the conditional fields module's functionality.